# Reading the first n rows of a csv without parsing the whole file in Power Query

Tags: powerquery, m

I have these csv data files with my relevant data in the first five rows and a bunch of mal formmatted data below it. When I use filter rows it still reads in all of the data below which causes problems for me. This is problematic because I am reading in a whole folder's worth and some of these files have a different number of columns below the rows I'm interested in. Those columns or data below those first five rows I do not need, but power query throws errors when it is looking for the same number of columns as the last file. I would like it to just read in the first n rows which are uniform between all files in the folder.

Is there a way to do this or bypass the error? Let me know if there is anything else I can provide to help my question be better understood.

I have already tried filter rows, but that still reads the whole document and throws some errors.

This is similar to what I'm looking for, but it's not clear how I can edit this to achieve what I want.

[Skip 6 rows before "reading" into powerquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39535275/skip-6-rows-before-reading-into-powerquery)

Ultimately I'm going to be reading in the first 5 rows of all documents in the file folder. This is much easier in Pandas, but I need an Excel solution for a coworker. The error I get is "unexpected number of columns." I have confirmed this with doing a subset of files that has the same number of columns for the lower extra data I don't need. I would like a solution robust enough to handle all of the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load a CSV into the Query Editor, it will likely generate M code like this:

```
let
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\FilePath\FileName.csv"), [Delimiter=",", Columns=3, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, {{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}, {"Column3", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Delete the last step, `#Changed Type`, and change `Columns=3` in the first step to the number you actually want instead of what it automatically detected.

Comment: I would rather it not try to read in any of those columns at all. Say there are 300 files in the folder, 200 of those may have 7 columns and 100 will have 10 columns. I would still like to read all of the folders, not craft it to just read for 7 or or 10.

Comment: If you have variable columns I believe it's fine to simply remove the "Columns=" parameter and it will load all available columns in any given file.

Comment: Thanks, I believe this changed type was creating my problem. I realized I did actually want to use this format for a single file because I am applying the query portion as a function to all files in the folder. Essentially I'm doing something like this. Thanks again Alexis, I really appreciate you explaining what is happening in the answer below too.

Answer (score 1):

If you're loading from a folder, then you can write a query along these lines:

```
let
    Source = Folder.Files("C:\FilePath\FolderName"),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Extension] = ".csv")),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Content", "Name"}),
    #"Extracted First 5 Lines" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Removed Other Columns", {{"Content", each Table.FirstN(Csv.Document(_),5)}}),
    #"Expanded Content" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Extracted First 5 Lines", "Content", {"Column1", "Column2", "Column3"})
in
    #"Expanded Content"
```

With the key part being this transformation:
`each Table.FirstN(Csv.Document(_),5)`

When you create that last step, it will expand to as many columns as it sees. If you want to make it more dynamic, then try something like this instead of the `#"Expanded Content"` line:

```
MaxColumns = List.Max(List.Transform(#"Extracted First 5 Lines"[Content], each Table.ColumnCount(_))),
#"Expanded Content" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Extracted First 5 Lines", "Content", List.Transform({1..MaxColumns}, each "Column" & Number.ToText(_)))
```

This makes sure you have enough columns for the widest table in the `#"Extracted First 5 Lines"` step.